# Create plot with relative time point in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   ID Var1 Var2 Month BeforeAfter
1   1   23    4     1       FALSE
2   1   41    5     2       FALSE
3   1   32    2     3       FALSE
4   1   58    1     4        TRUE
5   1   60    7     5        TRUE
6   2   12    3     1       FALSE
7   2   34    4     2       FALSE
8   2   55    5     3        TRUE
9   2   49    5     4        TRUE
10  2   60    6     5        TRUE
11  2   64    9     6        TRUE
```

I want to create a plot (for example with `ggplot`) to show the before and after a certain treatment for `Var1`. Thus, I want that the treatment time/x-axis to be at 0 and the months relative to the treatment should be around it. The `FALSE` values indicate the time before the treatment and the `TRUE` values the time after the treatment, whereas the first `TRUE` indicates the treatment time. So I expect an output similar to this:

[image]

I searched for a solution, but nothing really came up and as I am new to R I do not know where to start, so I would be happy about any suggestions.

Thank you!

---

Edit: Larger data sample:

```
larger_sample <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11),
                     Var1= c(121,134,101,17,90,71,40,93,59,34,38,85,127,92,78,51,116,51,39,105,118,142,13,123,53,101,59,128,37,126,94,46,131,131,134,37,148,60,120,55,28,102,28,137,51,87,69,113,63,46,98,59,30,44,16,124,58,137,30,135,50,79,122,69,93,89,129,124,91,29,90,145,126,103,93,102,79,15,83,64,20,133,68,49,27,127,144,24,124,138,133,60,135,37,126,22,87,144,105,26,150,150,48,88,118,48,125,61,149,48,56,46,93,80,78,28,74,36,97,31,36,81,69,19,128,118,56,62,93,40,96,23,119,101,16,113,57,90,101,149,31,48,103,83,50,20,40,94,140,91,16,121,106,130,109,46,12,135,62,148,144,70,107,117,24,69,13,14,34,35,59,129,20,18,90,139,13,94,38,41,65,68,45,48,128,52,62,96,70,44,47,25,43,52,68,102,67,59,144,51,109,100,41,63,87,46,145,12,138,63,123,36,102,66,72,65,62,113,50,53,80,91,44,119,29,141,14,117,87,121,121,117,35,139,33,116,144,67,149,80,128,113,59,30,29,147,61,141,20,61,150,114,134,134,46,20,19,130,66,120,143,70,121,96,124,38,144,84,97,148,31,120,132,86,71,107,19,13,104,111,82,144,56,43,115,85,123,108,150,73,67,146,35,143,127,136,56,46,40,136,45,60,79,84,59,87,42,121,73,50,40,46,90,107,47,14,34,146,87,71,85,12,75,143,41,31,25,136,16,20,96,21,60,69,25,39,38,63,17,43,90,67,48),
                     Month= c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26),
                     BeforeAfter= c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Month = Month - Month[which(BeforeAfter)[1]], ID = factor(ID)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Month, y = Var1, linetype = ID)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  xlab("Time relative to starting treatment (months)")
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

```r
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), Var1 = c(23L, 41L, 32L, 58L, 60L, 12L, 34L, 55L, 49L, 60L, 
64L), Var2 = c(4L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 9L), Month = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), BeforeAfter = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"))
```

---

**EDIT**

To get the mean and confidence intervals at each time point, it would be best to summarise your data before plotting:

```r
larger_sample %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Month = Month - Month[which(BeforeAfter)[1]]) %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  filter(n() > 2) %>%
  summarise(Mean = mean(Var1),
            upper = Mean + 1.96 * sd(Var1)/sqrt(n()),
            lower = Mean - 1.96 * sd(Var1)/sqrt(n())) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Month, y = Mean)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), fill = NA, colour = "black",
              linetype = 2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  xlab("Time relative to starting treatment (months)")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is what I wanted regarding the x-axis and it looks great. But I would like to have one graph for the different ID groups that is composed of the others. Sorry I did not clarify that in my question.

Comment: @Mina do you mean an average of `Var1` at each time point? Or an average with confidence intervals as in the sample image? Your data aren't sufficient to support this at present. Do you want to include a larger data sample in your question so I can demonstrate?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, something came up. I just meant the mean at each time point. However, I also included a larger data sample if you want to show also the case with the confidence intervals for anyone who comes across this and is interested in the example in the image above. :)

Comment: @Mina thanks - see my update with your new data.